# how to change label with button in vb?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, function

so i want to have a button the changes the text of a label when i click it and it says page not available, but when i comment out the update panel it atleast shows up.

```
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="s1" runat = "server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<div>
<h1>UpDaTe PaNeL tEsT PaGe</h1>
start text : Hello <br />
updated text: World<br />
    <hr />

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="p1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Update"  OnClick="updateLabel" Height="29px" Width="110px"/> -->
        Text: <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="hello"></asp:Label>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>    
</div>
</form>
```

codebehind

```
   Public Class aaaa
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub

Function updatelabel() As String
    Label1.Text = "World"
End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the OnClick from the button and Try the classic method of handling events. 
So your code will be... ( Sorry I'm posting it via app so it might not be in code view )

```
Protected Sub ChangeLabel(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Label1.text = "TextGoesHere"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is correct. The handler for the Label Click event needs the `sender as Object` and the `e as EventArgs` parameters. If you do not put them, your `updateLabeL()` function will not be a valid match for the event handler.